# Плагин All Autocomplete в Sublime Text 3 не работает

Tags: sublime-text, sublime-text-3

В общем все в загловоке, может это из за версии? в предыдущей кажется все работало как надо, в настройках параметр "auto_complete": true, уже теряюсь в догадках, попробовал удалить один из файлов в директории саблайма как пишут [здесь](https://toster.ru/q/256723), но результата также не дало (и файла уже нет :), хотя что с этим файлов что без него все равно не работает, что посоветуете?

Comment: Я так понимаю это из за версии самого саблайма, нужно ждать очередную стабильную версию кажись, а то в DEV BUILD просит ключ ввести

Comment: Попробуй сделать как в этой статье написано, мне помогло!)
Вот ссылка: http://sridhar.blog/enable-autocomplete-css-selectors-sublime-text/

Comment: @Иван Орлов подскажи как правильно ввести текст в ком строке саблайма, а то когда ввожу то получаю invalid syntax